# Error connecting to workgroup Remote Desktop client printer from domain host computer

Tags: remote-desktop, network-printers

I'm connecting remotely from home (Workgroup) Win7 PC to an office (Domain) Win7 PC using VPN and Remote Desktop. Remote Desktop connects fine but doesn't share my local resources no matter what I do. So to print from host (office) to client (home) I've set up printer network sharing (it's an HP printer connected at home via USB) and created a separate regular user without login privileges. Every several weeks something happens and the connection stops working.

Most recently, connection attempts to the remote printer return error 0x00000709.

Troubleshooting I've done:

1. Turned off firewall on both RDP client (home) and host (office) computers
2. Confirmed \\x.x.x.x\c$ is accessible from host to client
3. Cleared all connections using "net use" in command prompt (\\x.x.x.x\IPC$ usually appears after I open explorer to the client machine IP address and authenticate with the workgroup user account)
4. Confirmed the client VPN IP address is the same (when it changes, I have to reconnect the printer via explorer)
5. On client, tried to connect to printer via \\localhost in explorer and got the same error.

It drives me crazy that this works for a while and then stops with no apparent rhyme or reason. Windows updates might be the cause but the last update since this last happened was Microsoft Removal Tool (this morning) and it doesn't make sense this would cause the problem.

Any ideas what to try next?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, disabling IPv6 on the home PC's Local Connection adapter resolved the issue.

During troubleshooting, I was able to connect the office PC to another home PC (connected over AnyConnect VPN client) for file and print sharing, further complicating root cause analysis. I used WireShark to check outgoing packets from the office PC but was unable to check incoming packets on either home PC due to encryption on the VPN interface. WireShark revealed SMB connections were being successfully requested, opened AFAIK, and closed.

The issue was temporarily resolved when I rebooted both the target home PC and the Cisco ASA. This resulted in a new VPN IP address being assigned to the home PC. The issue returned 1-2 days later. Logging into the office PC with a different domain account did not resolve the issue. Disabling IPv6 on the home PC's Local Connection adapter did resolve it. I thought to do this after noticing the public IP address given on whatismyip.net was an IPv6 address, where in the past I've always seen an IPv4 address.

I hope this helps someone.